# Gitlab Child Pipeline get vars from dynamic yml

Tags: typescript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, variable-assignment, playwright

Hi all hope someone can help. I'm unable to find the answer after days of searching. Trying to give as much detail as possible.

My goal is to run each Playwright test in their own k8s pod. The test is in a foreach loop, within a describe. The test data is retrieved from a JSON file storing the data. Each test name is different and works fine.

I got the idea from [This quick tutorial](https://bkirova.medium.com/gitlab-child-pipeline-with-dynamic-configuration-in-5-minutes-6950c4d3fdd6) but does not show variables.

I have 2 issues.

1. I'm running an older Gitlab version - 13.x. So Im unable to use trigger:include:artifact (get error artifact key not found)

My trigger stage requires the dynamically generated yml file, which gets data from the JSON file saved in artifacts. How can I download this file into the required trigger stage?

When I push my code to Gitlab, I have different stages.

**Problem: When I push new code to source:

- build runs fine
- generate-config runs fine
- trigger-test runs fine
- downstream (child) pipeline runs fine
- pods in k8s start, but fail because variable TESTNAME is not assigning the value I am assigning, show $TESTNAME
- the test pods are not created because the job name show as $TESTNAME-(00000000) - pipeline_id. Because the name is not in the correct format.**

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  SOME_VARIABLES: $SOME_VARIABLES
  USER: $USER
  PASS: $PASS

stages:
  - build
  - generate
  - trigger

build:
  ... works

generate-config:
  ... works and saves to artifacts

trigger:
  ... works but triggers from yml file in root
```

dynamic-test.yml

```
.TEST_DEPLOY
  extends: dynamic-test-run

.dynamic-test-run:
  image: myimage
  tags:
   - runner-tag
  script:
   - apply job.yml
  ....

test-one:
  extends: TEST_DEPLOY
  variables:
    USER: User1
    PASS: mypass1

test-two:
  extends: TEST_DEPLOY
  variables:
    USER: User2
    PASS: mypass2

test-three:
  extends: TEST_DEPLOY
  variables:
    USER: User3
    PASS: mypass3
```

job.yml

```
code for job.yml
spec:
  ...spec yml
    spec:
     containers: 
       ... container code
       env:
         -name: USER
          value: $USER
         -name: PASS
          value: $PASS
         command:["npx", "playwright", "test"]
      ...
```

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1syO7.png)

Comment: Adding variables and assigning values in the trigger stage, does work, but I dont think that can be done dynamically from JSON file.